# NServiceBus: Remove Deferred messages when calling MarkAsComplete()

Tags: c#, nservicebus

Using NServiceBus 3.2.7. When calling MarkAsComplete (A person cancels their order while there are deferred messages out.) It appears that calling MarkAsComplete does eliminate the saga, but the messages that were previously deferred are still in the timeout queue. When they finally process, they get caught in a SagaNotFound exception. I would like to be able to notably tell the difference between a legitimate saga not found and one that was thrown because the saga had been removed due to a cancelled order.

How can you remove the deferred messages from Raven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inherent race condition here between the timeout and the cancellation. It could be that the timeout is already on its way to be delivered when the cancellation happens, so it cannot be cleared.

It is for exactly this reason that NServiceBus raises SagaNotFound as an event and not an exception.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Udi, I'm sorry I meant Event and not exception. We are handling the SagaNotFound events and determining the message type that was not found. I suppose my issue is the ill knowledge of which messages were cancelled vs. which messages have an issue for one reason or another as to why the sagas were not found. I suppose it would be better in my case to record the cancelled sagas and validate that the sagas being inquired about were in fact cancelled and not caused by another issue. 

I was thinking there was inherent functionality in NServiceBus that handled this.